# IBM Watson Conversation: How to dynamically create context variables?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In IBM Watson Conversation, [context variables](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-build.html#context) can be used to carry information. A value can be derived from the [evaluation of expressions](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html) as shown:

```
"context": {
    "mycity": "<? entities['city'].value ?>"
  }
```

What I tried is to dynamically compose the variable name:

```
"context": {
    "my<? @animals ?>": "my new value"
  }
```

However, the expression in the variable name is not evaluated. How can I define a variable name based on available data such as intents, entities or other context variables?

Comment: Not possible without application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution seems to be to do it in the application:

- Receive response object including all the metadata.
- Extract necessary data
- Compose context object to be passed back into Watson Conversation for next message processing. Create new variables as part of this preparation.
- Call [message API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#messages) with context object which includes new variable.
- New variable is available during Watson Conversation-internal processing.

Comment: Yes... As right now the names of the context variables cannot contain a SpEL expression.